# Backbone.js Model Post

Tags: backbone.js

Im building an application where I need to POST data to a server. At this point the only thing I have been using models for is to receive/fetch data in the app. Now I want to POST. I was wondering how to do that in a good way. I guess by a model called "postmodel" or something?

I basically just want to call on an api and pass some params. Like this kind of:

```
/api/?action=answerQuestion&question_id=*my id here*
```

How would I do something like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you would have to do is create a new function within your model and perform the request "manually" from that function. Something like this:

```
MyModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
  initialize: function(){
    ...
  },
  post_to_api: function(){
    var data = { 
      "question_id": this.id,
      "action": "answerQuestion"
    };
    $.post( "http://api.com/", data, function( response ) {
      // post success callback
    });
  },
});
```

Then to use this, you would instantiate `MyModel` and call the `post_to_api` function:

```
var model = new MyModel( { "id": 42 } );
model.post_to_api();
```